# Linking the Allegro library to a C++ application using the g++ compiler (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linker, allegro

In trying to get Allegro (A C++ game programming library) to work with a very simple C++ application in Ubuntu 12.04, I am unable to get the program to compile with the allegro header definitions. It returns the error **allegro.h - no such file or directory found**. I tried running a pkg-config to find the proper linker command, but that didn't help in compilation.

I am almost certain it is installed correctly at this point. I tried using a pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5.0 for the include file paths, none of which worked when using in the g++ compile line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/pkgfiles`? Or something like `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/dir make` if you are using make? the pkg-config lists the lib among the list of handled packages? `pkg-config --cflags liballegro` what outputs? ...

Comment: So your current problem is compiling. Linking comes when that one is solved. Have you tried setting INCLUDE or adding `-I/path/to/allegro/headers` to the compiler flags?

Comment: pkg-config with --cflags returns a -I, -L and -lallegro, I tried all three of them in the g++ compile line and it still says it cannot find the header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a **pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5.0** told me wrong on the include path. It told me to use **-I/usr/local/include** and after some digging into that folder, I found that the include path is **-I/usr/local/include/allegro5** instead. It is compiling fine now.